# about the boundedness of solution as $x\to -\infty$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation $\displaystyle{\frac{dy}{dx}=y-\sin y}$. Show that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that if $|y_0|<\epsilon$, then the solution $y=f(x)$ with $f(0)=y_0$ satisfies $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x)=0}$.

==========================================

Clearly the function $f_1(x,y)=y-\sin y$ is Lipschitz on any domain $D$ in $\mathbb{R}$. So in the rectangle $R$ defined by $|x|\leq h$, $|y-y_0|\leq k$; where $\displaystyle{h<\frac{k}{\max (f_1)}}$, $\max(f_1)$ defined over $D$, there exists a unique solution of the given equation for $|x|<h$. How to predict from here that the solution approaches zero when $x\to -\infty$?